# Orchard Microdata Breadcrumbs

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms, breadcrumbs

I am trying to add microdata to Orchard CMS 1.8.1 breadcrumbs.

I need to add itemprop="child" to breadcrumbs.cshtml taken from /Core/Shapes/Views of which I added to my theme views folder. I works fine but it does not display the itemprop="child", I added as .Itemprop.Add("child") to the below breadcrumbs code.
But the child attribute does not show up

```html
@{
    // Model is Model.Menu from the layout (Layout.Menu)
    var tag = Tag(Model, "ul");
    tag.AddCssClass("breadcrumb");

    var items = (IList<dynamic>)Enumerable.Cast<dynamic>(Model.Items);

    if(items.Any()) {
        items[0].Classes.Add("first");
        items[items.Count - 1].Classes.Add("last").Itemprop.Add("child");
    }
}
<nav itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    @tag.StartElement
        @* see MenuItem shape template *@
        @DisplayChildren(Model)
    @tag.EndElement
</nav>
```

I have added to MenuItemLink.cshtml in my theme views folder which gives me all the microdata for breadcrumbs but the child attribute.

```html
<a itemprop="url" href="@Model.Href"><span itemprop="title">@Model.Text</span></a>
```

How or where can I add the itemprop="child" to orchard and get it working as everything is added by
@DisplayChildren(Model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
items[items.Count - 1].Classes.Add("last").Itemprop.Add("child");
```

to

```
items[items.Count - 1].Classes.Add("last");
items[items.Count - 1].Attributes.Add("itemprop", "child");
```

items[items.Count - 1] - it is Shape class. Classes - it is `IList<string>` collection classes for shape.
Attributes - it is `IDictionary<string, string>` collection attributes for shape.